# How is the internal ScheduledExecutorService behavior

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm working in streaming app. As a part of the application i implemented an adaptative streaming algorithm. During the tests, i just used i hack in part of decoding in order to delay the frames decoding process.

However, this hack is done by using a random increasing delay on a `ScheduledExecutorService` with `public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit);`

What i noticed is there is frames who are sent after other ones which are decode BEFORE. Is `schedule()` asynchronous ?

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService is a thread pool so everything it does is asynchronous.

Comment: If you want to provide data dependencies between frames decoding, you can use CompletableFuture.thenAsync and other similar methods. Using delays for this purpose is totally wrong.